# Google Cloud Storage Transfer Service API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm wondering how to interpret the option `overwriteObjectsAlreadyExistingInSink` in the [GCS Transfer Service specification](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec#transferoptions).

The description given is:

> When to overwrite objects that already exist in the sink. The default is that only objects that are different from the source are ovewritten. If true, all objects in the sink whose name matches an object in the source will be overwritten with the source object.

From testing it out, it seems as if "different" only applies to the contents of the file and not the metadata, such as `generation`. Is there any official way to confirm what is meant by "different"?